# shasum returns an incorrect result

Tags: linux, encryption, hash

Calculating SHA256 gives me an incorrect result when I'm using "shasum":

```
$ echo "abcd" | shasum -a 256
fc4b5fd6816f75a7c81fc8eaa9499d6a299bd803397166e8c4cf9280b801d62c  -

# or

$ echo abcd | shasum -a 256
fc4b5fd6816f75a7c81fc8eaa9499d6a299bd803397166e8c4cf9280b801d62c  -
```

And in ruby:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require "digest"
=> true

irb(main):005:0> Digest::SHA256.hexdigest("abcd")
=> "88d4266fd4e6338d13b845fcf289579d209c897823b9217da3e161936f031589"
```

Online generators give me the result as ruby does.

Why isn't the result of "shasum" correct?

Answer (score 5):

This is because `echo` adds a new-line character to the end of its output, by default. Try using:

```
echo -n abcd | ...
```

instead, which suppresses the new-line at the end.